# Why does the UTF8 tick character arrive differently?

Tags: php, curl

When I look in the HTML source of a form I'm filling in, I get:

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
```

However, when I submit the form (having called urlencode on each name and value), the browser's request body shows:

```
utf8=%E2%9C%93
```

I get that both decode into the same tick character, but why are they different? I'm asking for an automatic test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input value is [html entity](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) representation of the character. In this case, it has the same effect in the browser as if you wrote the actual character as value:

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" />
```

**The server already accepts the unicode character** as POST field, not the entity string.

After you run urlencode() on the character, you get its encoded value, which is `%E2%9C%93`.

If you didn't run urlencode() on the field, you'd get the actual character:

```
array(1) { ["utf8"]=> string(3) "✓" }
```

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? How do I convert one into the other?

Comment: @JohnFF: You wrote in your question "having called urlencode on each name and value". Which means you already converted the `✓` into `utf8=%E2%9C%93` by using `urlencode()` on the field... My last sentence in the answer says the value would still be `✓` if you didn't use the urlencode().

Comment: Just to be clear for anyone reading: 

urlencode(html_entity_decode('&#x2713;')) == '%E2%9C%93'